# Multisite User cannot access dashboard

Tags: multisite, admin

I am dynamically creating a new blog which sets a newly created user(this user is created in woocommerce) as the main site admin.  However when the user trys to login into the dash the following error is displayed:

`You attempted to access the "blog name" dashboard, but you do not currently have privileges on this site`

It then lists the same blog as the site the user does have access to ...

Your Sites
`"blog name"    Visit Dashboard | View Site`

The only I can think that is causing this is that I have hacked wordpress to allow nested paths, and the blogs url follow this structure: `domain.com/s/blog-name`.

Could anyone suggestion to why this is happening?